# How to show the long list of cards in the best possible manner in web UI

Tags: user-centered-design

I'm using a card layout in web for showing some info. Currently there are 4 to 5 cards in each row and the container can show upto 20 cards in one view.  If there are total of 150 to 200 cards, currently there is a scroll. There is no limit for cards in the UI. From a minimum of 10 cards to maximum can go till 500 cards.

What is the best way to show this info in the UI. Is the usage of pagination make sense for this type of UI?

Comment: do you have a mock showing your efforts at the moment? Also, is there a reason for cards vs a tabular view?

Answer (score 1):

Just place it in rows of let's say 4 cards and have the app load the cards when the user reaches the bottom of the screen. YouTube does this when you are looking at a user's uploaded videos.

[image: YouTube videos page]

Don't forget to add a "Load more cards button". It comes in useful when the user's internet cuts or they have a slow connection. They can request for more of the info to show, which will mean they don't need to restart the whole page just so they can try reach whatever card they were looking for.

Pagination has it's place, but at the current moment, there's a trend away from this and towards a more continuously flowing page. Pagination, I feel, adds a sort of friction point. Imagine if you had to click a "load more tweets" (or Facebook posts) button each time you reached the bottom of the page. This really starts to get annoying quick. And we all know an annoyed user is an angry user, and an angry user is the type of user that will close your tab quickly. (btw, using a "load more x" button is a form of pagination).